# Need to Replace by JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Need to `Replace` by jquery.

MY Json is:

```
var money={"money1":"957.06","money2":"1,368,737.85"}
```

Need to get result:

```
var money={"money1":"957.06","money2":"1368737.85"}

var res = money.replace(/,/, "");
```

by this its replaceing all the ","how to slove this?

Comment: This isn't related to jQuery; it's just JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to iterate thru every value and then replace in it:

```
var money={"money1":"957.06","money2":"1368737.85"}
$.each( money, function( key, value ) {
 value = value .replace(/,/, "");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use **JavaScript** `replace()`

e.g.:

```
money.money2 = money.money2.replace(/,/g, "");
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Answer (score 0):

Add a `g` (global) flag to your regex; otherwise, only the first match will be replaced. Also, you need to access the actual properties of `money` that contain values:

```
money.money1 = normalizeMoney(money.money1);
money.money2 = normalizeMoney(money.money2);

function normalizeMoney(str) {
  return str.replace(/,/g, '');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just with JavaScript (without jQuery):

```
var money={"money1":"957.06","money2":"1,368,737.85"};

Object.keys(money).map(function(value, index) {
   money[value] = money[value].replace(/,/g, '');
});

console.log(money);

// Object {money1: "957.06", money2: "1368737.85"}
```